# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry

Tags: java, android

I have two projects and one is used as an library but each class have same dependencies than the error arise,but how to solve it? I need all the dependencies in each project.

**Error message:**

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':toretan:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/brickred/socialauth/Feed.class
```

Comment: if you add same dependencies in both place as in library and project than you delete in 1 place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had also this problem and solution was kind of simple.

Find dependency that is causing problem in this case it would be `Socialauth`,and try to change its version to lower or higher.